# Setting up H2 database in Spring + Hibernate without XML File yields NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I have a problem regarding the proper setup of a H2 database in springboot + hibernate and would very much appreciate your help. I guess my problem is in the @Transaction Annotation, since the respective class throws a NullPointerException. Here is some background information:

- The idea of the program (which is not yet finished) is that agents (class "AgentLogic") can calulate prices for specific tasks within a Multi-Agent System. In order to calculate the price, an agent draws parameters from a database. These parameters are needed for some Machine Learning algorithms (in class "MachineLearningSource"), which will calculate the price of the agent.
- I would like to setup the configuration of the database WITHOUT using an XML File, similar to the example in http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring
- The project has the following structure:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITX8X.jpg)

UPDATED CODE AFTER INCORPORATING CHANGES FROM @StanislavL

The project is implemented in SpringBoot. Accordingly, I use the following Application class:

```
package org.schlago.mldb;
import...

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
        builder.headless(false);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = builder.run(args);
        }
    }
```

The following class  contains the configuration of the database in Spring Hibernate, called DataBaseConfig:

```
package org.schlago.mldb.database;

import...
@Configuration
@Profile("param_db")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"org.schlago.mldb.mapping","org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning"})
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("datasource.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.show-sql"));
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

This configuration uses the following environment (@Profile) in order to setup the sessionFactoryBean, called appliation.yaml:

```
spring.profiles: param_db
datasource:
  driver: org.h2.Driver
  url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
  username: sa
  password:
jpa:
  hibernate.show-sql: true
  hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: none
  hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
  hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers: true
entitymanager:
  packagesToScan: org.schlago.mldb.mapping
```

Parameters shall be inserted to the database via a DAO, using a @Transactional Annotation. This DAO is called ParametersDao:

```
package org.schlago.mldb.mapping;
import ...

@Transactional
public class ParametersDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        return _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void save(Parameters parameters) { getSession().save(parameters); }

    public void update(Parameters parameters) {
        getSession().update(parameters);
    }

    public List<Parameters> getAllParameters() {
        return getSession().createQuery("from Parameters").list();
    }

    public Parameters getParameterById(int id) {
        List<Parameters> parametersList = getSession()
                .createQuery("from Parameters where paramId = :theId")
                .setParameter("theId", id).list();
        if (parametersList.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return parametersList.get(0);
    }
}
```

Parameters are specified via the Paramters class:

```
package org.schlago.mldb.mapping;

@Entity
@Table(name = "mlparam")
public class Parameters {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long paramId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private double value;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private Date timestamp;

    public Parameters(){
    }

    public long getParamId() {
        return paramId;
    }

    public void setParamId(int paramId) {
        this.paramId = paramId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) { this.timestamp = timestamp;   }
}
```

I think there is an error in the way ParametersDao is setup. However, for your better understanding, here are the other classes used within this project. The following class is AgentLogic, which will calculate a price upon request in a later strange of the code. Since the code is still in an early stage, I used @PostConstruct rather than a request, in order to test if the price calulation works:

```
package org.schlago.mldb.logic;

import...

    @Component
public class AgentLogic {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private MachineLearningSource machineLearningSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        int priceInCent = 50;
        priceInCent = machineLearningSource.getPrice(getAgent());
        LOGGER.info("Answered with offer about " + priceInCent + " Cents.");

    }

    // DUMMY class: Return a new agent
    public static Agent getAgent(){

        // Currently, an Agent is just an (empty) dummy class
        Agent agent = new Agent();
        return agent;
    }
}
```

Finally, the following class is responsible for price calcuation. Since the code is still in an early stage, price calculation is set randomly, rather than implementing machinelearning algorithms. In the method getParameters(), some Parameters are inserted to the dataBase for testing purposes:

```
package org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning;

import org.schlago.mldb.Nodes.Agent;
import org.schlago.mldb.mapping.Parameters;
import org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

    @Component
public class MachineLearningSource {

    @Autowired
    ParametersDao parametersDao;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MachineLearningSource.class);

    public int getPrice(Agent agent) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int thePrice = r.nextInt(99) + 1;
        LOGGER.info("The price is dynamically calculated right now!");
        HashMap<String, Double> parameters = getParameters();

        return thePrice;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getParameters() {
        HashMap<String, Double> equationParameters = new HashMap<>();

        // TEST: Since database is currently empty, parameters are inserted manually here (this will change later)
        LOGGER.info("About to insert into table");

        Parameters myCalcParams = new Parameters();
        myCalcParams.setName("kappa");
        myCalcParams.setValue(2.39583992);
        myCalcParams.setTimestamp(new Date());

        parametersDao.save(myCalcParams);

        LOGGER.info("Successfully inserted parameters");


        /*
        // Get the parameters via parametersDao, work in progress!
        List<Parameters> parameters = parametersDao.getAllParameters();

        Parameters myParam = parametersDao.getParameterById(3748);
        if (myParam == null) {
            LOGGER.info("Dataset does not exist!");
        }

        for (Parameters param : parameters) {
            equationParameters.put(param.getName(), param.getValue());
            LOGGER.info("Actual parameter for price calculation: " + param.getName());
            LOGGER.info("Value: " + param.getValue());
        }
        */


        // TEST: Return dummy equationParameters
        equationParameters.put("a", 2.48238948239);
        equationParameters.put("b", 8.23482489729);

        return equationParameters;
    }

}
```

UPDATED ERROR STATEMENT

Unfortuntely, I still get an error:

```
    2017-02-03 14:41:39.005  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.schlago.mldb.Application             : Starting Application on mobile-97 with PID 7416 (C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Masterarbeit\12_MLDBtest\target\classes started by Jan in C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Masterarbeit\12_MLDBtest)
2017-02-03 14:41:39.005  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.schlago.mldb.Application             : The following profiles are active: param_db
2017-02-03 14:41:39.083  INFO 7416 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@79ca92b9: startup date [Fri Feb 03 14:41:39 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-03 14:41:40.581  INFO 7416 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'databaseConfig' of type [class org.schlago.mldb.database.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$829d3967] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-03 14:41:40.721  INFO 7416 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
2017-02-03 14:41:41.004  INFO 7416 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-02-03 14:41:41.020  INFO 7416 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-02-03 14:41:41.129  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2017-02-03 14:41:41.129  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-02-03 14:41:41.129  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-02-03 14:41:41.394  INFO 7416 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2017-02-03 14:41:41.521  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-02-03 14:41:41.693  INFO 7416 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-02-03 14:41:42.363  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-02-03 14:41:42.432  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-02-03 14:41:42.510  WARN 7416 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agentLogic': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning.MachineLearningSource org.schlago.mldb.logic.AgentLogic.machineLearningSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'machineLearningSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning.MachineLearningSource.parametersDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-02-03 14:41:42.510  INFO 7416 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-02-03 14:41:42.510  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-02-03 14:41:42.559  INFO 7416 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-02-03 14:41:42.559 ERROR 7416 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agentLogic': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning.MachineLearningSource org.schlago.mldb.logic.AgentLogic.machineLearningSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'machineLearningSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning.MachineLearningSource.parametersDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning.MachineLearningSource org.schlago.mldb.logic.AgentLogic.machineLearningSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'machineLearningSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning.MachineLearningSource.parametersDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'machineLearningSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning.MachineLearningSource.parametersDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning.MachineLearningSource.parametersDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.schlago.mldb.mapping.ParametersDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 

2017-02-03 14:41:42.575  INFO 7416 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/Documents/Masterarbeit/12_MLDBtest/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.33/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/com/sparkjava/spark-core/1.1.1/spark-core-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-server-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-http-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-util-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-io-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-webapp-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-xml-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-servlet-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-security-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/net/sf/xenqtt/xenqtt/0.9.7/xenqtt-0.9.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20151123/json-20151123.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/com/pi4j/pi4j-core/1.0/pi4j-core-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.54/bcprov-jdk15on-1.54.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.54/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.54.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.192/h2-1.4.192.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/org/opcfoundation/ua/1.02.337.10/ua-1.02.337.10.jar, file:/C:/Users/Jan/.m2/repository/com/prosys/ua/server-client-sdk/2.2/server-client-sdk-2.2.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202016.2.5/lib/idea_rt.jar]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@Component` annotation to the `MachineLearningSource` service class and check both dao and the service are included in the `@ComponentScan`

UPDATE

In the AgentLogic you manually create the machineLearningSource

```
    MachineLearningSource machineLearningSource = new MachineLearningSource();
    priceInCent = machineLearningSource.getPrice(getAgent());
```

Instead add

```
@Autowired
private MachineLearningSource machineLearningSource;
```

To the class to let Spring initialize this properly. Or you can autowire dao in the class and manually call

```
machineLearningSource.setDao(theAutowiredDao);
```

UPDATE2:

Now the dao is not marked to be detected as a spring bean. Add `@Repository` annotation to the DAO.

UPDATE3:

```
sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));
```

check which exactly packages are scanned there. Need to have all packages where your entity classes are stored.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback @StanislavL . I did as you suggested: I added `@Component` to MachineLearningSource and explicitly set `@ComponentScan({"org.schlago.mldb.mapping","org.schlago.mldb.machineLearning"})`. Unfortunately, I still get the same error; the parametersDao seems to be Null...

Comment: Thank you so much @StanislavL . This is a very good point. I updated my code and accordingly updated the code posted in my question above. However, now I get a different type of error statement. However, the core of the statement - if i got that right - is that the parametersDao is not initiated...

Comment: Thanks @StanislavL. I did that and now get another error `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.schlago.mldb.mapping.Parameters` must the Parameters class also have a `@Components` annotation? sorry for bothering you that long...

Comment: You have Entity annotation on the class. It's enough. May be something with component scan

Comment: Updated once more. Leaving... will continue on Monday:-)

Comment: Alright - thank you very much for your time and help! I will let you know if it worked out :)

Comment: I made sure that all the packages are scanned correctly. It is still not working. I worked on the problem over the weekend some more along with my supervisor, but we still couldn't fix it. The problem seems to be that all the bean wirings diminish once the MachineLearningSource (@Component) is instantiated... I think that SpringBoot and the configuration of a sessionFactory via @Configuration is the root of the problem. Setting up a sessionFactory with hibernate.properties and hibernate-config.xml works fine. For that reason, I will throw in the towel and try to setup the database with .xml

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @StanislavL - I very much appreciate it!